# Replacing in a complicate expression

Tags: replacement

I have a complicate expression like this

```
2 a g12 (b (-1 + b c) g12^2 + b (1 - b c) g11 g22 + c g22^2) +
 g22 ((-1 + b^2 c^2) g12^2 + c^2 g22 (-b^2 g11 + g22)) + 
 a^2 (g12^2 g22 + b^2 g11 (g12^2 - g11 g22))
```

and would like to expand it and replace `g11 a^2 + 2 g12 a c + g22 c^2` with `g11`. Tried out Expand, Replace, Collect, Sort, etc. but it didn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe `In[2980]:= 
PolynomialReduce[
  2 a g12 (b (-1 + b c) g12^2 + b (1 - b c) g11 g22 + c g22^2) + 
   g22 ((-1 + b^2 c^2) g12^2 + c^2 g22 (-b^2 g11 + g22)) + 
   a^2 (g12^2 g22 + b^2 g11 (g12^2 - g11 g22)), 
  g11 a^2 + 2 g12 a c + g22 c^2 - g11, 
  Join[Complement[Variables[eee], {g11}], {g11}]][[2]]

Out[2980]= 
b^2 g11 g12^2 - 2 a b g12^3 - b^2 g11^2 g22 + 2 a b g11 g12 g22 - 
 g12^2 g22 + a^2 g12^2 g22 + 2 a c g12 g22^2 + c^2 g22^3` ?

Comment: This sort of thing probably qualifies as an FAQ on this site, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?

```
expr = 2 a g12 (b (-1 + b c) g12^2 + b (1 - b c) g11 g22 + c g22^2) + 
  g22 ((-1 + b^2 c^2) g12^2 + c^2 g22 (-b^2 g11 + g22)) + 
  a^2 (g12^2 g22 + b^2 g11 (g12^2 - g11 g22));
rep = g11 a^2 + 2 g12 a c + g22 c^2;
expr = Expand[expr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now

```
Simplify[expr,rep==g11]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't think you need `expr = Expand[expr]`, do you?

Comment: @anderstood no, ofcourse not. But I just wanted to show the expression when expanded on the screen, since OP said he wanted to expand it. But internally, it work without explicit expand ofcourse. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is what I'm looking for but I'm not sure... Is it possible to see, before it simplifies, how it explicitly collects the expression g11 a^2 + 2 g12 a c + g22 c^2 on one side (or in a parentheses) and only later replaces it?

Answer (score 2):

You could try `Eliminate` to eliminate either `g22` or `g12`:

```
Eliminate[{
    eq1 == 2 a g12 (b (-1 + b c) g12^2 + b (1 - b c) g11 g22 + 
      c g22^2) + g22 ((-1 + b^2 c^2) g12^2 + c^2 g22 (-b^2 g11 + g22)) + 
      a^2 (g12^2 g22 + b^2 g11 (g12^2 - g11 g22)),
    g11 a^2 + 2 g12 a c + g22 c^2 == g11
  },
  g22
]
```

If necessary you can then use `Solve` and `Simplify` to solve for the temporary variable `eq1`:

```
Simplify[eq1 /. First @ Solve[%, eq1]]
```